# php api connection code for bigcommerce not working

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using Web Matrix on a Windows machine with composer, and also have uploaded the same code to a windows server.

i have written my code in PHP to connect to Bigcommerce API but it just won't connect!

```
<?php
 echo "made it";

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


     Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com',
    'username' => 'demo',
    'api_key' => 'df38dd10e9665a3cfa667817d78ec91ee9384bc3'
    ));


    Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('rsa_rc4_128_sha');
    Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);


$products = Bigcommerce_Api::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;

echo " at bottom";
?>
```

I've read the other posts, but nothing seems to help.  The first echo statement runs, but nothing else, including the bottom echo.

Please don't tell me to use curl as it's murder to install in windows!
HELP!

Comment: Can you provide any error messages or anything?  Also, `vendor/autoload.php` is referenced as though it is a local file on your server.  Can we see this file as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change Bigcommerce_Api to Bigcommerce

```
<?php
echo "start";
require "bigcommerce.php";
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com',
    'username' => 'demo',
    'api_key' => 'df38dd10e9665a3cfa667817d78ec91ee9384bc3'
    ));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}
echo "end";
?>
```

Comment: it's important to note here that, although the documentation says you can use one executable for the api, you really have to download the whole zip and compile with composer.